# Get the previous UINavController

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, xcode8

How do I refer to the previous view controller. I want to use an if statement something like the following:

```
if previousViewController = searchController {
 //preform a method
}else if previousViewController = notificationController {
 //preform another method
}
```

but how do I get reference to the previous view Controller? So for example if I clicked a button on view controller A that takes me to view controller B, I want to somehow get reference to view controller A. I've looked at similar questions but I can't seem to find an answer that helps me enough.  Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "previous view controller"?

Comment: Sorry I should explain myself better. So if I click a button on view controller A that takes me to view controller B I want to get reference to view controller A. does that make sense? @AshleyMills

Comment: Is B presented as a modal VC ? Or pushed using an UINavigationVC ?

Comment: presented as a modal VC @nathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred way around this would be to add a property to `ViewControllerB` to show it's usage. For example…

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    enum Mode {
        case search, notify
    }

    var mode = Mode.search

    override viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() {    
            configure()
        }
    }

    func configure() {
        switch mode {
        case .search:
            // configure for search results
        case .notify:
            // configure for notification 
        }
    }
}
```

then in the presenting view controller:

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {        
        if let mvc = segue.destination as? MyViewController {
            mvc.mode = .search
        } 
    }
}
```

or set `mvc.mode = .notify` if presenting from your `NotificationViewController`

Using this method, `MyViewController` doesn't need to have any knowledge of how or by what it was presented. You could push it onto a nav stack, or change `SearchViewController` to `DownloadViewController`, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: ignore my last comment. It works perfectly! Thank you very much